# Segmentation Fault - Can different glib-c version do something like that?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, glibc

I have some trouble with memory allocation / deallocation.

On a "64-bit machine" i run some c-code that gave me no error.
If i run the same code on a 32-bit machine (after re-compile it, obv.) i have some segmentation-fault trouble.

This is mine glib-c version:

> Package: libc6
>   New: yes
>   State: installed
>   Automatically installed: no
>   Version: 2.13-20ubuntu5
>   Priority: required
>   Section: libs
>   Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers 
>   Uncompressed Size: 10,7 M
>   Depends: libc-bin (= 2.13-20ubuntu5), libgcc1, tzdata
>   Suggests: glibc-doc, debconf | debconf-2.0, locales
>   Conflicts: belocs-locales-bin, belocs-locales-bin, libc6-amd64, libc6-amd64,
>              prelink (< 0.0.20090925), prelink (< 0.0.20090925), tzdata (<
>              2007k-1), tzdata (< 2007k-1), tzdata-etch, tzdata-etch
>   Breaks: nscd (< 2.13), nscd (< 2.13), libc6 (!= 2.13-20ubuntu5)
>   Replaces: belocs-locales-bin, belocs-locales-bin, libc6-amd64, libc6-amd64,
>             libc6 (< 2.13-20ubuntu5)
>   Provides: glibc-2.13-1
>   Description: libreria C GNU embedded: librerie condivise

On 32-bit machine the version is:

> 2.06-01

More over, here comes the snippet of code that drive me crazy:

```
void estrai_libro (FILE* fileDescriptor, Libro* libroLetto) {

char* ptr_buf;
size_t n;
size_t lung;
ssize_t nread;

/* ---- questo blocco di istruzioni verrà utilizzato per tutti
    i campi della struttura Libro passata in input */
/* inizializzo ptr_buf e n rispettivamente a NULL e a 0 in moda da
   da sfruttare al meglio la getline(...)*/     
ptr_buf = NULL;
n = 0;
/* copio all'interno del buffer ptr_buf il contenuto di una riga
       del file; la funzione getline legge dal file fino a quando non
   incontra uno \n (ecco perchè io formatto gli input) */
nread = getline (&ptr_buf, &n, fileDescriptor);
/* calcolo la lunghezza della stringa letta */
lung = strlen (ptr_buf);
/* istanzio una zona di memoria della stessa dimensione della stringa
   letta e fatta puntare dal campo titolo della struttura Libro */
libroLetto->titolo = (char*) malloc (lung*sizeof(char));
/* inizializzo la zona di memoria istanziata con degli 0 */
memset (libroLetto->titolo, 0, sizeof(libroLetto->titolo));
/* copio la stringa letta e contenuta in ptr_buf nel campo titolo
   della struttura Libro passata in input (libroLetto). */
strcpy (libroLetto->titolo,ptr_buf);
free (ptr_buf);
/* ---- fine blocco*/
ptr_buf = NULL;
n = 0;
nread = getline (&ptr_buf, &n, fileDescriptor);
lung = strlen (ptr_buf);
libroLetto->autore = (char*) malloc (lung*sizeof(char));
memset (libroLetto->autore, 0, sizeof(libroLetto->autore));
strcpy (libroLetto->autore,ptr_buf);
free (ptr_buf);
ptr_buf = NULL;
n = 0;
nread = getline (&ptr_buf, &n, fileDescriptor);
lung = strlen (ptr_buf);
libroLetto->editore = (char*) malloc (lung*sizeof(char));
memset (libroLetto->editore, 0, sizeof(libroLetto->editore));
strcpy (libroLetto->editore,ptr_buf);
free (ptr_buf);
ptr_buf = NULL;
n = 0;
nread = getline (&ptr_buf, &n, fileDescriptor);
lung = strlen (ptr_buf);
libroLetto->data_pubblicazione = (char*) malloc (lung*sizeof(char));
memset (libroLetto->data_pubblicazione, 0, sizeof(libroLetto->data_pubblicazione));
strcpy (libroLetto->data_pubblicazione,ptr_buf);
free (ptr_buf);
ptr_buf = NULL;
n = 0;
nread = getline (&ptr_buf, &n, fileDescriptor);
lung = strlen (ptr_buf);
libroLetto->num_pagine = (char*) malloc (lung*sizeof(char));
memset (libroLetto->num_pagine, 0, sizeof(libroLetto->num_pagine));
strcpy (libroLetto->num_pagine,ptr_buf);
free (ptr_buf); 
ptr_buf = NULL;
n = 0;
nread = getline (&ptr_buf, &n, fileDescriptor);
lung = strlen (ptr_buf);
libroLetto->num_copie = (char*) malloc (lung*sizeof(char));
memset (libroLetto->num_copie, 0, sizeof(libroLetto->num_copie));
strcpy (libroLetto->num_copie,ptr_buf);
free (ptr_buf);
ptr_buf = NULL;
n = 0;
nread = getline (&ptr_buf, &n, fileDescriptor);
free (ptr_buf);
}
```

Anyone have ideas?

My first was about glib-c version but now I can'

t reach 32-bit machine and "update" that lib. So, someone can address me?

**edit:** Just to be clear, the segmentation fault come before free(ptr_buf)

Comment: I have one idea - please format the code so we have a hope of reading it.

Comment: And what does the `gdb` debugger tells you?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : I din't try it, because i'm not such good in c programming. I've studied it some years ago and, now, i'm helping a friend so, this isn't my code directly. How can I use that `gdb` debugger?

Comment: `gdb` has an extensive documentation, with a tutorial section. http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/ and I also suggest to compile with `gcc -Wall -g`

Answer (score 6):

```
 libroLetto->titolo = (char*) malloc (lung*sizeof(char));
 memset (libroLetto->titolo, 0, sizeof(libroLetto->titolo));
```

`sizeof(libroLetto->titolo)` is the size of the pointer member and not the allocated object.
What you want is: `memset(libroLetto->titolo, 0, lung)`

You may also want to check the return value of the `getline` function everytime you call it, otherwise `strlen` may get you unexpected results.

Last but not least:

```
lung = strlen (ptr_buf);
libroLetto->autore = (char*) malloc (lung*sizeof(char));
```

You are not allocating room for the trailing null character, what you want is `malloc(lung + 1)`

Comment: Is `free` that drive me to seg.fault

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do all this copying. I suppose getline() already does the allocation for you.

```
void estrai_libro (FILE* fileDescriptor, Libro* libroLetto) {

char * ptr_buf;
size_t n;

ssize_t nread;

n = 0;
libroLetto->titolo = NULL;
nread = getline ( &libroLetto->titolo, &n, fileDescriptor);

libroLetto->autore = NULL;
n = 0;
nread = getline ( &libroLetto->autore, &n, fileDescriptor);

libroLetto->editore = NULL;
n = 0;
nread = getline ( &libroLetto->editore, &n, fileDescriptor);

libroLetto->data_pubblicazione = NULL;
n = 0;
nread = getline ( &libroLetto->data_pubblicazione, &n, fileDescriptor);

libroLetto->num_pagine = NULL;
n = 0;
nread = getline ( &libroLetto->num_pagine, &n, fileDescriptor);

libroLetto->num_copie = NULL;
n = 0;
nread = getline ( &libroLetto->num_copie, &n, fileDescriptor);

ptr_buf = NULL;
n = 0;
nread = getline ( &ptr_buf, &n, fileDescriptor);
free (ptr_buf);
}
```

FYI: before c99 standardised readline(), different versions of readline() already existed. (and circulated in c.l.c). These had **slightly different function signatures**. Compile with at least -Wall to check for function prototype mismatches.

UPDATE: oops, that was getline() and this is readline(), but compiling with maximal warnings is probably a good idea anyway.

UPDATE: getline started as a gnu extension and was standardised by posix in 2008.

Comment: *beffore c99 standardised readline()*: neither `readline` nor `getline` are c99 functions

Comment: Oops. I stand corrected. Is it a gcc extension? BTW it appears they were standardised into posix in 2008. I'll edit.

Comment: `getline` was originally a GNU extension and now part of POSIX

Answer (score 0):

Here is my test program that proves there really is an issue. I also sent this to Ubuntu but it has not been posted by them yet:

Here is the test program:

---

```
#include        <objc/Object.h>
#include        <dmalloc.h>

main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  size_t len;
  char *fname;
  char *rootname = "TESTFILE";

  len   = strlen (rootname) + 1;
  fname = (char *) calloc (len,1);

  printf ("rootname=%s len=%d\n", rootname,len);
}
```

---

Compiled with this line:

```
    gcc -o tst tst.m -ldmalloc
```

and it gives this result:

```
$ ./tst
rootname=TESTFILE len=9
Segmentation fault
```

---